# Access denied when trying to delete S3 Object from node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

i am using S3 bucket for uploading and getting image from S3 server. image is uploading and fetching fine but whenever i try to delete the object it says Access denied, i am unable to find which permission i am not giving in permission roles
here is my node js code which i am running local on my machine.

```
import S3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
const region = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;

const s3 = new S3({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey
});

const deleteFile = (filekey) => {
  try {
    const deleteParams = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: filekey
    };
    return s3.deleteObject(deleteParams).promise();
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};

export default deleteFile;
```

here is the response
[image: img]

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the IAM Role.

Comment: in roles i have attched policy of full access of bucket

Comment: at first i assigned read write access but late i have created new policy of full access of bucket but no luck still get error on deleting object of s3 bucket.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show us your code, the _exact_ error message and the permissions associated with the IAM Role. Please also tell us where you are running the code (on your own computer, on an Amazon EC2 instance, in an AWS Lambda function)?

Comment: please check now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a little mis understanding when it comes to `roles`.Roles are used when you want one aws service to talk to another aws service, so basically by roles you are giving permission to one service to talk to another service.

by in your case you are not using aws service, so roles are not the problem.THe problem is with bucket policies.In order to do operations in your bucket, you need to give permission for the particular bucket

check this sample policy -> this example, you want to grant an IAM user in your AWS account access to one of your buckets, `awsexamplebucket1`, and allow the user to add, update, and delete objects.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

for more check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-policies.html

Comment: Agreed. Since the code is apparently running on the OP's computer, it is using credentials from an IAM User, not an IAM Role. Either the IAM User does not have the necessary permissions, or they are trying to access a bucket that is not in the same AWS Account as their IAM User.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an object in Amazon S3 requires `s3:DeleteObject` permission on the appropriate bucket (or all buckets).